# Filter/Mask one of the parameter passed as argument in perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script which takes a bunch of parameter as input. Depending on input different set of business logic is executed.

In one of the case i am getting password as input. This password is getting logged as it is in log file. This is the situation i am trying to avoid.

1. Either i want to mask the password argument and then log OR
2. Completely ignore this entry.

Sample code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

print Dumper \@ARGV;
```

Now lets say i call the above script as :

```
test.pl -a='getData' -b='abc' -password='xyz' -c='pqr'
```

Now output looks like this :

```
$VAR1 = [
      '-a=getData',
      '-b=abc',
      '-password=xyz',
      '-c=pqr'
    ];
```

so instead of logging the password as it it, ( from security perspective ) I want to mask the field. Output something like below :

```
 $VAR1 = [
      '-a=getData',
      '-b=abc',
      '-password=*******',
      '-c=pqr'
    ];
```

Few things here:

1. I cant override the input args passed since i will be needing the password value in next step of processing
2. input argument ***a*** will always have value 'getData' whenever password parameter is present in input
3. For different value of input parameter ***a***, there will be no password field.
4. Order of parameter may vary sometime

Comment: Just iterate through the arguments and if the key is `-password` don't print it?

Comment: is there any other way to do this, i was trying to avoid the iterating part in case -password is not at all present.

Comment: At least on *nix, the password will be stored in the user's history file and appear in the process table no matter what you do in your script. Masking the password in your application logs may help, but it certainly won't make the script secure.

Comment: You don't have a specific question here. It sounds like you have to write a program that requires password input, and would like to feel better about it being secure. You can't have someone enter a text string on the command line and have it visible only to certain parts of your software: the entire command line will be logged before your program ever sees it. It sounds like you need to forget about the command line and hand control to a secure method of getting access to whatever the password is for. It is access to that resource that your program requires, not the password itself

Comment: On many systems, the password can be hidden from the process table by manipulating `$0`.

Comment: @Borodin: the code i am referring to is part of a bigger business logic and code flow process. Script gets call automatically and all necessary data is being retrieved from some secure database. I cant explain the overall logic here, but question i have posted is very simple and explains my problem very easily. I can understand what your point is but as i have said in other comment that is no concern. My part is to make sure that does not get log. Whatever else happens is others story

Comment: Umm, passing a password via command line is NEVER secure. Don't do it period...

Comment: *"My part is to make sure that does not get log. Whatever else happens is others story"* Several people have tried to tell you that your approach will not work as it is impossible to hide the text of a command line. Unless you tell us more about *"Whatever else happens"* that is the only help that we will be able to give you.

Comment: Why is the post down voted.  I cant share all necessary details and i tried asking my question in simplest possible way. I can understand the security details which everyone is talking but my question was straight forward. Security and other details are something not related to my query ( but maybe with overall details which you guys are specifying  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a copy of the password field from `@ARGV` before you do anything else, then mask that copy to be used for logging. `@ARGV` will contain the original unmasked version.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($masked_pw) = grep /-password=.*/, @ARGV;

if ($masked_pw){
    my $mask = '*****';
    $masked_pw =~ s/(-password=).*/$1$mask/;
}
```

I'm with @ThisSuitIsBlackNot though... the password will still be available elsewhere.

Comment: I agree it wont be 100% secure but my end is to make sure that it does not get log. Rest will be take care by different parts of team. Let me try the masking thing and see if it works

Comment: also this case will fail when password field is not even present as input. How to make sure that corner case like that is also covered

Comment: What do you mean it'll fail? Nothing will happen. if `-password=` isn't present, no errors or warnings will be displayed, simply nothing will happen.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the script to tell the user that the `-password` argument is required?

Comment: this wont work as password field is overwrite. If i want to use that in next step i cant use because original value is now replaced with ***.

Comment: i want to retain the original value of the field. While logging only i want to hide the value